# The PayPal API Details - I've confused myself

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a website that acts as a broker for a transaction, which the customer can pay using PayPal.

Scenario

The Website(Adam) accepts payment using PayPal from the Customer(George), but pays the money to a third Paypal account (Fred). Adam gets no money. But Adam needs to provide an Api Signature, password etc as the owner of the website to make the calls.

1) I am assuming right now, that if I provide the API details from Adam's PayPal account (Business), Adam is going to get the payment rather than Fred - who is the intended receiver?

2) Do I need to apply for an adaptive account rather than just plugging in the API details as I had originally thought?

3) How do I make Fred get the money from George, by only using Adam as the broker/gateway?

Comment: `PaymentDetailsType paymentDetail = new PaymentDetailsType();

                //Details of the receiver of monies
                SellerDetailsType sellerDetails = new SellerDetailsType();
                sellerDetails.PayPalAccountID = "Fred";
                paymentDetail.SellerDetails = sellerDetails;

PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(sdkConfigForAdamsAPI);
                SetExpressCheckoutResponseType setECResponse = service.SetExpressCheckout(wrapper);`

Would this work? So using Adams API but Fred gets paid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Adam does not need to keep any funds at all, and you're simply building a checkout that uses Adam's API credentials but sends the money to Fred, then I would recommend using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).

The Express Checkout experience is a little nicer, more feature packed, and does not require you to get an app approved like Adaptive Payments does.

Express Checkout consists of 3 API calls.

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

You can use the PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTREQUESTID parameter in the SEC and DECP calls to specify Fred's PayPal email or account ID, and the money will be dropped directly into that account.

If you happen to be working with PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It will make those API calls very quick and easy for you.

Comment: I am using the .net tutorial from here; https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/dotnet?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

Each time I make the call API call, I pass in Adams API details. Can I simply change this to use Freds details each time instead (on the fly) as it sounds like to do Express Checkout, no parties need to register their details to use the API this way?

Comment: Yeah, a lot fo the documentation skips over this part. If you have Fred's credentials then yes, you can use those credentials to simply "be" fred to PayPal. But you can also use your own (Adam's) credentials plus the subject= parameter to have Adam process on behalf of Fred, who would receive the money. This does require that Adam grant Fred this permission to act on his behalf. Seach for "subject=" in this doc, for example: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/

Comment: As I mentioned, though, if you use Express Checkout with the PAYMENTREQUESTID parameter then you don't have to bother with granting permissions and using the subject parameter.